# getOrDefault for Map<String, ?>

Tags: java

Trying to getOrDefault for Map like:

```
String test = map.getOrDefault("test", "")
```

But it gives me an error "Required ? but got a String". Anyway to get around this?

Comment: Which error? Can you add the stack strace to the question?

Comment: Also plese post the declaration of the variable map.

Comment: What if `map` is a `Map<String, Integer>` concretely? This wouldn't then be type correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values of a `Map<String, ?>` could be of any type.

`getOrDefault` requires the second parameter to be of the same type as the values; there is no value other than `null` which can satisfy this, because you don't know if that `?` is `String`, `Integer` or whatever.

Because you are only retrieving a value from the map, you can safely cast to a `Map<String, Object>`:

```
Object value = ((Map<String, Object>) map).getOrDefault("key", "");
```

This is because you are not putting any value into the map which would make calls unsafe later; and any value type can be stored safely in an `Object` reference.

Comment: You could of course avoid the cast with ternary conditional: `Object v = map.containsKey("key") ? map.get("key") : "";` or check that the result is not `null` as in: `Object v = map.get("key"); if (v == null) v = "";`. (However, the latter can be inconsistent with the result of `getOrDefault` if the map allows `null` values.)

Comment: @Radiodef you could, but 1) that defeats the point of the `gOD` method (and perhaps means that you do the lookup twice, whereas `gOD` allows it to be done just once); 2) maps can contain null values, so that check is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of this method returns the given default value (generics - can be any type) if not found (AKA null).

```
  default V getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue) {
        V v;
        return (((v = get(key)) != null) || containsKey(key))
            ? v
            : defaultValue;
    }
```

documentation link attached: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-